# How can i validate for special character at particular position in regexp

Tags: regex

I have written **Regexp** `@"^([a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)$"` it allows all the characters and numbers except special characters and first characters cannot be numbers. Now I have to allow `'-'` character anywhere except last and first character. How can i modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
@"^([a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z0-9\- ]*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)$"
```

- The first group allows only letters (at least one)
- The second group allows any character (- included)
- The last group allows only letters and numbers (at least one to
  exclude any other character)

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: `[a-zA-z0-9- ]` <-- this may not do what you intend.  Did you test your code?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `-` to the second character class and add [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` to make sure the string does not end with `-`.

[`^(?!.*-$)([a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/UWx4ys/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!.*-$)` Negative lookahead to assert that the string does not end with `-`
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[a-zA-Z ]+` Match character class one or more times
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*` Match character class with `-` zero or more times
- `)` Close capturing group
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

**Note**

Your regex is inside a capturing group. If you don't use that group you might leave out the parenthesis: 
[`^(?!.*-$)[a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/9rgZ7S/1)